# App icon not showing up on emulator

Tags: android

I created a simple splash screen application, and it works just fine only when i click the "Run" button in eclipse indigo, and I am not able to find the icon at all in the emulator.
Where is icon?! I ran it as android 4.0.3.

Comment: have you define any of your activity as main in manifest?? and make sure in manifest app:icon tag have some drawable

Comment: ankit, got what i wanted. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, you want to find your application on the emulator? If it ran fine, it should be there in the app drawer like so:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I hadn't bothered to scroll down the app drawer, i found it at the end of it.